# Issues with Ajax load more request for CPT loop inside foreach based on categories

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I have a WordPress custom post type, on it's archive page I have a foreach loop based on custom taxonomy. For each item returned from loop, a have_posts/ the_post loop displays posts assigned to that category long with a button to request more posts via Ajax for each row in the category foreach loop.

The problem I am facing is that no matter which button I press all loops return the same results, which aren't new post just existing displayed results that override what was already displaying.

The JS for loop recognises which .loadmore has been clicked, but all the buttons update the data for the third .response, doesn't seem to recognise the iteration.

I think the issues relates to this, that there isn't correlation between el[i] (eg 2) and res[i] (eg 2), but i'm not sure on how to achieve this.

Any tips would be appreciated :)

**Ajax.js**

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const el = document.querySelectorAll('.loadmore');

  // Loop over all loadmore buttons
  for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {

    el[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      console.log('Which loadmore clicked: ' + [i]);

      const res = document.querySelectorAll('.response');

      // Loop over response for each output
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

        xhr.open('POST', WP.ajax, true);

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;');

        xhr.onload = function () {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {

            // Update response div 
            res[i].innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

            console.log("Fired?");
            console.log('Which res: ' + [i]);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            // console.log(this.xhr);

            WP.current_page++;
          } else {
            console.log(this.xhr);
          }
        };

      }

      // xhr.send(data);
      xhr.send('action=loadmore&query=' + WP.posts + '&page=' + WP.current_page + '');

    },
      false
    );
  }
```

**Archive-CPT.php**

```html
$categories = get_terms('category_factsheets');

/**
 * Loop over each category 
 */
$i = 0; foreach ($categories as $category): ?>

<div class="container--slim">

  <div class="factsheet-group">
    
    <h2><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>

    <div id="response_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="response inner">

      <?php
      $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category_factsheets',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $category->term_id
          )
        )
      );
      /**
       * Loop over each category to display all associated posts
       */
      if (have_posts()): query_posts( $args ); while (have_posts()): the_post(); 
        $factsheet = get_field('factsheet'); 
        ?>
        
        <div class="factsheet-item">
          <h3><?php echo $factsheet['issue_date']; ?></h3>
          <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
          <?php if ($factsheet['pdf']): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $factsheet['pdf']; ?>" target="_blank">View PDF</a>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div><!-- inner : END -->
    

    <div class="loadmore btn btn--black">View more</div>
  
  </div><!-- factsheet-group : END -->

</div><!-- container--slim : END -->

<?php $i++; endforeach;
```

**Functions.php**

```html
function factsheets_loadmore_ajax_handler() {

  $categories = get_terms('category_factsheets');

  $params = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
 $params['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
  $params['post_status'] = 'publish';
 
 // it is always better to use WP_Query but not here
 query_posts( $params );
 
 if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post();
    
    // the_title();
    $factsheet = get_field('factsheet'); 
    ?>
      
      <div class="factsheet-item">
        <h3><?php echo $factsheet['issue_date']; ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <?php if ($factsheet['pdf']): ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $factsheet['pdf']; ?>" target="_blank">View PDF</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>

  <?php
  endwhile; endif;

 die; // here we exit the script and even no wp_reset_query() required!
}
 
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'factsheets_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'factsheets_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
```

Comment: In your `factsheets_loadmore_ajax_handler` function, what does your `$params` array look like before you `query_posts`? Make sure your json is being decoded properly here (if you haven't yet).

Comment: @TimHallman Thanks for that, if I run `$dump = json_decode( $params, true );
  var_dump($dump[0]);` it returns `NULL` so guessing somethings going wrong there as well.

Comment: @TimHallman updating the $params now returns:

`array(4) {
  ["post_type"]=&gt;
  string(6) "awards"
  ["paged"]=&gt;
  int(2)
  ["post_status"]=&gt;
  string(7) "publish"
  ["tax_query"]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    [0]=&gt;
    array(4) {
      ["taxonomy"]=&gt;
      string(19) "category_factsheets"
      ["field"]=&gt;
      string(2) "id"
      ["terms"]=&gt;
      string(7) "term_id"
      ["operator"]=&gt;
      string(2) "IN"
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: Do you get anything with just `var_dump($dump)`? If not, I believe that's your issue, everything else looks like it's correct.

Comment: perhaps the `stripslashes` is garbling your encoding?